# ENUM storage (memory, etc)

Tags: java, performance, memory, enums

I was just asking myself a little question, and I'm not sure if I can find the right answer to this:

If I use an ENUM in Java, with an own constructor (and many, many, maaaaany parameters) - are those stored in Memory every time the program gets executed, or are they only 'loaded' in Memory, if they get used?

What I mean is, if I have an ENUM with 400 entries, and only use one of the entries - are all others still present in Memory?

**some pseudocode:**

```
public enum Type {
    ENTRY_A(val1, val2, val3, val4, new Object(val5, val6, val7, ...)),
    ENTRY_B(val1, val2, val3, val4, new Object(val5, val6, val7, ...)),
    ENTRY_C(val1, val2, val3, val4, new Object(val5, val6, val7, ...)),
    ...
}
```

If I only use ENTRY_A, and dont touch ENTRY_B, ENTRY_C, etc - how will Java handle that exactly?

Thanks for the Answer - and yes, this is mainly curiousity

Comment: The question should be rather: "Why have you created such a monster?".

Comment: @Jagger That would have been, definitively, a better and more interesting question. I agree :-)

Comment: Well, that's the point of my question, to avoid creating such a monster if it's not necessary - and use a configuration or data source for it. But since the data wont change too often, it could as well just be an enum instead (but since apparently it is loaded in Memory, that's not the way to go then) - so the idea behind this question is to find an answer to the question: 'do I do this as ENUM, or as data-file?' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes everything will be loaded to memory even though you use only one ENUM constant.

Enum  is special type of class and all fields are constants, so when you load the ENUM, then itself it loads everything to memory.

Answer (score 4):

The first time you use the enum, that will trigger the class initialization and all values will be created and stored in memory just as it happens with any other class.

Comment: Is it possible to let javac do some optimization?

Comment: @fwonce What do you mean by optimization? What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try it by yourself. Just put for example `System.println("test")` in the constructor of your `enum` and empirically embrace the results.